# How can we run reports/queries in MKS through unix

Tags: unix, mks, mks-integrity

How to run reports/ Queries MKS, from UNIX without opening MKS.

Comment: When you say "without opening MKS" do you mean "from the command line"?

Answer (score 1):

go to mks installation directory location in your unix machine..
Say cd  /opt/mks/integrityclient/bin

You can see 'si' over there..

Just give command :  si help
you can see list of executable commands..

Get the syntax for reports..
si reports I guess would be syntax..

Please make sure you run all of above commands from mks installation bin directory..

Hope it helps..